# How to get SVN log to only display files in the current target

Tags: svn

When looking at the log of a folder in Tortoise SVN, you can filter out files which aren't in the folder.

The checkbox says: "Hide unrelated changed paths".

How can I accomplish the same with `svn log`?  I want the `verbose` output of the tool to not display file paths that aren't inside the current target.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution but:

Using a tool such as grep or UltraEdit on Windows, I was able to only display the lines I wanted by filtering with the following regular expression:

```
(r\d\d\d\d.+)|(.+/<FolderPath>/.+)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested and was unable to get the behavior you want from the command line.  Grepping the log output appears to be the best solution.